# how to use if else conditon on button press based on image of button?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to use some logics on the base of button click.i use button as checkmark and when i click on this check mark the image of button changed into checked.png or unchecked.png.On that basis i use this code...

```
if([UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_ticked.png"])
    {
        isActiveStr=[arrayPickerData objectAtIndex:17];
        NSLog(@" is active value is %@ ",isActiveStr);
        isActiveStr=nil;

    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"no vlaue send");
        isActiveStr=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"1"];
        NSLog(@" is active value %@",isActiveStr);
    }
```

Now i dont know how to use the else condtion...i run this code but it always run only if codition.It never goes in else conditon.I want that i codtion is true it goes in if part and when condition is false it goes in else part.And how i use image property of button to check the condition.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have a flag variable that holds the status of the button(checked/unchecked).

```
BOOL checked;
```

And, you have to update it when ever you click on the the button.

```
- (void)onButtonTapped:(UIButton *)button {

    checked = !checked;
    ...
}
```

And change your if statement like this,

```
if (checked) {

    // The button is checked

} else {

     // The button is not checked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `if` statement:

```
if ([[myButton imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage    imageNamed:@"checkbox_ticked.png"]]) {
...
```

But as for me this is bad approach, better to have some bool flag that indicate that button is checked.

Answer (score 0):

the if condition will always evaluate true. You should instead check for [myButton state] to see if it's enabled or not. You may have to add an IBOutlet or IBAction according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

USE this in your IBAction method

```
if(!btnCheckbox.selected)
    {
        [btnCheckbox setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"check-out_h" ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btnCheckbox.selected=YES;
    }
    else {
        [btnCheckbox setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"check-out" ofType:@"png"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btnCheckbox.selected=NO;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)checkBoxIsHideNationWideClicked
{
    NSLog(@"nation wide button clicked");

    mybtn.selected=!mybtn.selected;
    defaultsCheckBox=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (mybtn.selected)
    {
        [defaultsCheckBox setValue:@"One" forKey:@"CheckBox"];

        NSLog(@" is active value is %@ is fetched succesfuly",hideNationWideStr);
        [CommonVar setHideNationwideData:hideNationWideStr];
        NSLog(@" is active value send to cmmon class %@ sent succesfuly",hideNationWideStr);
    }
    else
    {
        [defaultsCheckBox setValue:@"Two" forKey:@"CheckBox"];
        NSLog(@"no vlaue send");
        hideNationWideStr=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"1"];
        [CommonVar setHideNationwideData:hideNationWideStr];
        NSLog(@" is active value send to cmmon class %@ sent succesfuly",hideNationWideStr);
    }
}
```